# WordPress: how to display events in calendar from specific category in WP Fulcalendar plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, fullcalendar

I have installed WP FullCanlendar plugin, and it’s work fine, but I want to show posts from category, where I’m staying now.
It’s mean, that when I’ staying in “Sport” category, I want to see in calendar posts from category “Sport”.

How I can to pass category ID via parameters of shortcode?
Something like this: [fullcalendar category=”51″] ?

Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read in the documentation there is listing the events by category

> Category attribute: Supply a single id, slug or comma-separated ids or slugs (e.g.
>   "1,categories-slug,3") to limit the search to events in any of these
>   categories. You can also use negative numbers and slugs to exclude
>   specific categories (e.g. -1,-exclude-categories,-3). If you mix
>   inclusions and exclusions, all events with included categories AND
>   without excluded categories will be shown. You can also use & to
>   separate ids and slugs, in which case events must contain (or not
>   contain) both categories to be shown.

So in this way you can do the following if we assume that the slug name of the category is : "sport"

```
[events_list scope="tomorrow" category="sport"]<p>#_EVENTLINK </p>[/events_list]
```

if you want to display the calender with categirized events you can do the following if we assume the category_id is 2

```
[events_calendar long_events=1 full=1 country="US" category="2" year="2012" month="2"]
```

if you need any further help dont hasitate to ask me :)

Comment: Thank a lot, Fadi!
I have tried last few days, but didn't found this in a documentation.
You made me happy!

Comment: You are Welcome :) 
I found the documentation of the attributes on this hidden link :D
http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/event-search-attributes/